# Has Gradle any extension what downloads javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, java, gradle, npm

I am working on a java based web page. I use gradle for java libs, and I downloaded manually the js libs. And a question came up; Is there any option, that I can handle the js libs with java libs in gradle?
My **goal**, that handling the js libs as jar libs, so I can define them in a file, and the gradle download all the jar and js libraries.

Thanks the answers and tips in advance!

Edit:

Is there any way to connect **npm** to **gradle**? I mean, the gradle triggers npm, and it downloads the libs to the spec path (e.g.: `src/main/webapp/js/lib` as `jquery.min.js`). And that way, If I want to update the js libs, I can do it with gradle via npm.

Comment: If there is a tool for that, it most definitively is based on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) which is (becoming) the standard dependency manager for frontend code.

Comment: I know npm, and I use it with php, but I've never used it with java / gradle before. Can I set in npm, the path of the downloaded libraries?

Comment: What do you mean by "path of the downloaded libraries"?

Comment: I wonder that it may possible to download the js libs (with npm) to `src/main/webapp/js/lib`. That way I can handle the js libs with npm, and jar libs with gradle. Furthermore I think i can build in the npm install to the gradle

Comment: Frontend dependencies cannot just be downloaded to somewhere and then they magically work. You should look into module bundlers like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io) that allow you to merge several JavaScript libraries/files into modules.

Comment: Thx for the response. I know that is not as simple as it sounds, I use tapestry (with built-in requirejs) and I have to define all the js lib path in the code, but I wonder what if I can handle this stuff lil bit dynamically..